# Do CSS comments effect/disable CSS rules?

Tags: html, css

This may just be a glitch but it has happened many times for whatever reason which is probably my fault. I am not sure what is causing this problem but I was writing a CSS rule using an id selector (#time) and it had no effect on the webpage. (google chrome is my browser). I had some random comments I left for myself above the CSS rule, they were regarding another problem I had earlier with some rules being dependant on each other. After I deleted the comments the CSS code started working. I undid the delete to check if there was something wrong with the comments, but there wasn't. All of the CSS code is on an external stylesheet.

Something like this happened earlier where the CSS rules for a GIF image would not work until I deleted a rule that I had put into comments because I no longer needed it.

```
/* should i center the title in between the two columns? */

/*
if so heres code that may work
h3 {
width: 140px; /*280 420*/
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 280px;
}
*/

#time {
background-color: yellow;
border: 5px solid blue;
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 570px;
}
```

The entire #time rule was ignored. I checked to make sure the id matched and it did. I also used the inspect feature on google and when I clicked on

```
<div id="time">...</div>
```

it went straight to the user agent stylesheet default rules.

I do not really understand why it didn't work I am just wondering if the comments had something to do with it or if someone else knows why that happened or how I can prevent that from happening in the future. I know comments aren't supposed to have an effect on the code and I couldn't find stories of the comments doing something like this, so I am confused.

Comment: Be careful with nested block comments `/* /* */ */` try switching to just line comments. Is the code in your question exactly how you have it written or just comments added for the question?

Comment: And by careful me mean: That don't work at all. The first */ ends the comment.

Comment: @zero298 That's probably the answer here. Might be worth turning that comment into an answer, provided this question isn't a duplicate of something.

Comment: @zero298 Yes the code is the same. I see how nested block comments would mess the code up. I changed my nested comment to a single line comment. It is working now! Thank you this really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess based on your code sample, and if your actual code isn't exactly like the code that you have in your example, it may be wrong. However, languages with block comments, as in

```
/* comment */
```

Don't do well with nested block comments as in

```
/* /* comment */ */
```

So the CSS interpreter is likely misparsing your rule. Try fixing your nested block comment by converting it to just single line comments as in

```
// comment
```